# Launching an Android activity and act upon it once opened

Tags: android

I have this piece of code which basically should launch an activity and act upon it, for example, set its title :

```
void launchAnActivityAndSetItsTitle() {
    context.startActivity(intent);
    activityMonitor.getCurrentActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

The activityMonitor variable is a component which holds a reference for the current foreground activity.
It is set upon the onResume() of each activity in the app.

When I run this code, the activity launches only once this method is over, which makes the second command useless, as it sets the previous activity’s title, not the new launched one. Adding a delay before the setting of the title didn’t help.

When I debugged it, I saw that the the code of the second
command is consistently being called before the onCreate() of the required new activity (regardless of the delay I set between the two). My question is why.

Thanks

**EDIT - My need better explained:**

I know how to pass data to a new activity. I was interested in knowing the reason for this particular timing issue - why does the activity get  always launched AFTER the end of this code block/method.

According to my design, this method resides in a separate module, which is only responsible for executing a url (which is turned into a specific intent, according to a url matcher), and allowing a callback to be called after the execution of the url, i.e. after an a activity is launched.

In this example, the callback is actually a call to a method which tries to set the current activity's title (the callback method resides in the app module and is passed to the "url executor" module as an argument).

So now that I explained my need of this sort of generic approach, maybe you could give me tips on how you would do it, without falling into this "activity didn't really launched yet" problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Launching activities is an asynchronous operation in Android - calling `startActivity()` simply schedules the activity to be launched some time in the future. You either need to pass the data to the activity or get the launched activity to communicate back to the original activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to modify something in the activity being started by the intent I would recommend passing an `Extra` along with your `Intent` and getting that extra in the new activity `OnCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxxxxxxx);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    setTitle(i.getStringExtra("title");
```

To put an extra inside an `Intent` use `intent.putExtra("title", "newTitle");`

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to pass data to a new activity using the intent's extras. I updated my question to better explain my need.